# How to detect user click in elements using tagname javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect user click in elements using tagname javascript ?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6mg0fvL/)

```js
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.activeElement;
  if (elem && elem.tagName == 'SPAN') {
    alert(elem);
    clearInterval(monitor);
  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Click ON Span HERE</span>
```

When i tested my code it's not working and not any error report. How can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is no need to use jquery(if your code is written in pure JS). Elements like `span`, `div` can't receive keystrokes or be focused on (by tabbing to them), so they won't ever be the `activeElement`.

When there is no selection, the active element is the page's `<body>` or `null` Source [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

To make it active you can use `contentEditable="true"` and just click on it to see its working. See below snippet

```js
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.activeElement;
  if (elem && elem.tagName == 'SPAN') {
    alert(elem);
    clearInterval(monitor);
  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<span contentEditable="true">Click ON Span HERE</span>
```

As per the @mongkon mamiw comment the video tag doesn't have `contentEditable attribute` but it can be focused on playing video like,

```js
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.activeElement;
  if (elem && elem.tagName == 'VIDEO') {
    alert(elem);
    clearInterval(monitor);
  }
}, 100);
document.getElementById("vid").addEventListener('play', function() {
  this.focus();
});
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <source src="https://www.threadsbay.com/kkkk.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: But Why not work when change from span tag to video tag like this http://jsfiddle.net/8nvvg4oz/1/